# Generate XML files based on rows in CSV

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, csv, elementtree

I have a CSV and would like generate an **XML file based on each row in the CSV**. 
Right now it creates an XML file but only with the **last row in the CSV**.  How can I modify this script to generate an XML file for EACH row.  And ideally have **the filename based on the Column: "File / Entity Name"**.  See below for what I currently have, Thanks!

```
# CSV module
import csv
# Stuff from the XML module
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, tostring, ElementTree
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree


# Topmost XML element
root = Element('root')
number = Element('number')
# Open a file
with open(r'U:\PROJECTS\Technical Graphics\book1.csv') as f:

    for row in csv.DictReader(f):
        root = Element('gmd:MD_Metadata')
        tree = ElementTree(root)
        for k, v in row.items():
            child = SubElement(root, k)
            child.text = v
            reader = csv.DictReader(f)

    tree.write(open(r'U:\PROJECTS\Technical Graphics\test.xml','w'))
    print tostring(root)
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the value of Root here:

```
for row in csv.DictReader(f):
    root = Element('gmd:MD_Metadata')
    tree = ElementTree(root)
    filename = row.items()[7]  # where 7 is the column your interested in
    for k, v in row.items():
        child = SubElement(root, k)
        child.text = v
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        tree.write(open(r'U:\PROJECTS\Technical Graphics\' + filename  + '.xml','w'))
        print tostring(root)
```

Answer (score 0):

You only want to create the `csv.DictReader()` class once, rather than for each iteration of your loop.

Similarly, you only want to create your `root` XML element once.

Finally, the order of the items returned from `row.items()` is arbitrary, and not reflective of the order of the fields in the file.

Try this:

```
# CSV module
import csv
# Stuff from the XML module
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, tostring, ElementTree
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree


# Topmost XML element
root = Element('root')
number = Element('number')
# Open a file
with open(r'U:\PROJECTS\Technical Graphics\book1.csv') as f:

    root = Element('gmd:MD_Metadata')
    tree = ElementTree(root)
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        xml_row = SubElement(root, "row")
        for k in reader.fieldnames:
            child = SubElement(xml_row, k)
            child.text = row[k]

    tree.write(open(r'U:\PROJECTS\Technical Graphics\test.xml','w'))
    print tostring(root)
```